# Renaming an object referencing an empty name

Tags: python, scripting

[image]

I'm curious how to change the object name to empty in Blender like the picture above. If there is only one object, you can do it manually, but I have a lot of objects of that type and would like to know a script or method to collectively change them to the empty name that becomes the parent.

Comment: Two objects in Blender can't share the same name, so if you rename the mesh object, the empty's name will change, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
import bpy

# get first floor empty
emptys_1st = {e for e in bpy.data.objects if e.type == 'EMPTY' and e.parent == None}

def recursive(obj, top_name = None):
    name = obj.name
    if obj.type == "EMPTY":
        for ch in obj.children:
            ch.name = f"{name}.{ch.name}" if top_name is None else f"{name}.{ch.name}"
            if top_name is None:
                recursive(ch, name)
            else:
                recursive(ch, f"{top_name}.{name}")

    else:
        for ch in obj.children:
            ch.name = f"{name}.{ch.name}" if top_name is None else f"{top_name}.{ch.name}"
            if top_name is None:
                recursive(ch, name)
            else:
                recursive(ch, f"{top_name}.{name}")

# unexpected result if the name is already exist
for e1 in emptys_1st:
    recursive(e1)
```

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI4lC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI4lC.png) Your answer is fantastic. I just have one more question. As shown in the figure above, when extracting multiple fbx, the parent name is to be extracted with an empty state. What kind of script should I write?

Comment: What is empty state? Do you mean: make parent from a object to a new "EMPTY"?